# How to set up Rails app that has different types of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, orm, architecture

If I want to build a Rails app that has two different types of users, let's say one type is called *players* and the other one is *owners*, what is the best and most **efficient** approach to modeling the app?

Things to take into account:

- There should only be one Login, but different Registration forms that Owners/Players can use.
- *Owners* can have access to a control panel but *Players* cannot.
- *Owners* cannot share any of *Players* capabilities, but both need to be able to perform Login/Registration.
- I am **not** using Devise, so please do not suggest it.

Different Approaches I've considered:

- **Using `cancancan` gem**, but it does not really *seem* to meet my needs in the sense that I am **not** looking to create a user/admin hierarchical approach but rather a *if you're a Player, then you can see these pages and perform these actions but Owners cannot* and vice versa. Almost like splitting the app in two. `cancancan` seems that it would treat *Owners* as "Players with extra privileges", not different privileges entirely.
- **Creating separate models with separate login and registration forms**, which seems like a disaster waiting to happen. One small mixup between a *Players* table and the *Owners* table, especially with the primary keys, and that will be a world of trouble where people could end up logging in to the wrong accounts.
- **Creating a polymorphic or has_one relation toward an *Account* model**, which so far, seems like the best way to probably go about it. If I created a polymorphic *Account* model, I can store different types of *Players*/*Owners*, but how could I compare login credentials against all types?

I had been trying to find something on this matter regarding how to map this out and was surprised to not find an information on how to do this *without using Devise*. If anyone has any good links they can point me to that also address this matter (*without* Devise), please leave them in your answer! Thanks.

Comment: If the owner and player table is the same, you could add a `owner` and `player` column(or an `enum` that can be `owner` or `player`) to a single table, and upon session create direct them to a specific controller based on that column. This would work identically to having an `admin` flag. The RailsTutorial will help show how that could work https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users section 9.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest one `User` class with a `type` attribute that determines whether the user is a `Player` or an `Owner` (single table inheritance). This way you keep the registration logic in one place but can customize the forms depending on the user's class.

There must be alternatives to `cancancan` that help with what you want to do, or you can implement helpers yourself:

```
def can_access_control_panel?
  current_user.is_a?(Owner)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a way to separate one user from another. One way is to add an attribute to the User table so you can call `current_user.role` and it will return `"owner"` or return `"player"`.

I have used [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gem in the past. It lets you define which controller actions the current user is allowed to access. So as you create resources for your application, you can add a policy that specifies who is allowed to that given resource. This is the [repo](https://github.com/LuisMenjivar/wiki) to the application.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278939/rails-4-authentication-model-with-roles/30279412#30279412) might help you.